# passing template template argument that is specified left-most template parameter (without alias)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-templates

How to specify left-most template argument of template template argument?

### Example

`B<int,T2>` is a template class with 2 arguments.
`E<H>` is a class that receive "template template argument" `H<T2>`.
I want to pass `B` into slot `H` of `E<H>` like : `E<B<1>>`,`E<B<2>>`,`E<B<42>>`, etc.

However, I only found poor work around, e.g. alias `B1<T>=B<1,T>` then pass `B1` into the `H`-slot :-

```
class D{};                                  //a library class
template<template<class T2>class H>class E{ //a library, don't modify me
    //"H<T2>" is "B1<T2>" = "B<1,T2>"
    H<D> h;  //Here, T2=D, so "H<D>" = "B<1,D>"
};
template<int n,class T2> class B{};     //a user class
template<class T2> using B1 = B<1,T2>;  //a user class
int main() {
    E<B1> e;         //I prefer to call it like E<B<1>>. (main objective)
    //const int n=5;
    //E<B<n>> en;    //If it is possible, it would be nice. (side objective)
    return 0;
}
```

It works ([ideone demo](http://ideone.com/G3swJm)), but I have to alias the ones that I want e.g.   `B1<T>`,`B2<T>` .... `B42<T>`.
This approach is not so cute.       Is there a more elegant way?

I know that Macro or X-Macro is a possible solution, but I try to avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write a template alias alias. `B<1>` can't itself be a template, which would imply that you could write something like `B<1><int>`. Which would admittedly be useful on occasion. But you can just name that intermediate template:

```
template <int N>
struct X {
    template <class T>
    using apply = B<N,T>;
};

E<X<1>::apply> e;
```

It's not *quite* `E<X<1>>`, but it's quite a bit better than having to write `B1`, `B2`, ...